# Visual C# Access item from other class file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

im writing an application in visual studio and im trying to access a rich text box from an other class. This doesnt seem to work for me. Also how to i call a function from an other class?

My code:

```
namespace Test{
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1()
    {
        // I want from this place to access the MyClass.test("hello");
    }   
}
}

namespace Test{
class MyClass
{
    public void test (string text) 
    {
     // here i want to do richtextbox1.clear(); but the textbox is not available
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can be done in many ways. My favorite would be to declare the object of the "MyClass" class within "Form1" by passing the "this" pointer as an argument. Thus, the object of the "MyClass" class will have access to all the members and public functions "Form1". Included RichTextBox1.

```
namespace Test{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
    MyClass MyClassObject;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyClassObject=new MyClass(this);
            MyClassObject.test("hello");
        }   
    }
    }

namespace Test{
    class MyClass
    {

       Form1 parent;

       public MyClass(Form1 parentForm)
       {
             parent=parentForm;
       }
       public void test (string text) 
       {
         parent.richtextbox1.clear();
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of deleting and re-posting the same answer, you can click `edit` underneath your answer to improve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this. You can for example do it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myClass = new MyClass(this.richtextbox1);
        myClass.SetTextBoxText("hello");
    }   
}

class MyClass
{
    RichTextBox _textBox;
    public MyClass(RichTextBox textBox)
    {
        _textBox = textBox;
    }

    public void SetTextBoxText(string text) 
    {
        _textBox.Clear();
        _textBox.Text = text;
    }
}
```

This uses constructor injection to pass the textbox to operate on to the contstructor. In `Form1`'s constructor the `MyClass` is instantiated with a reference to the textbox, which is initialized in `InitializeComponent()`. Then when you call `SetTextBoxText`, the class clears the associated textbox's text and then sets it to the passed text.

This is more specific than the commonly suggested method: just pass the entire `Form1` instance to `MyClass`'s constructor after making the textbox `public`, but that way you cannot reuse `MyClass` for other forms.

But as you see, it's pretty pointless to do. You can let `Form1` contain `this.richttextbox1.Text = "hello";` directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear from your question, but I'm supposing your `richtextbox1` is located at `Form1`.

By default all UI elements of form has `private` acess modifier - that's why you can't access your `richtextbox1` from outer class.

You can change it's access mmodifier to `public` - but I **strongly** encourage you not to do it.

Instead write some method in `Form1` class like

```
public void ClearRichTextBox()
{
    richtextbox1.Clear();
}
```

and use it.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention it. Why i shouldn't make it public?

Comment: You should not make your UI control public because it will break incapsulation. If your richtextbox will be public - then any code can access it, modify it, and make anything with it - even set it to null. Instead you should expose to public only nessesary methods for manipulating your objects.